# Can't get back to the Ulimit default parameters in Linux

Tags: linux, ulimit, nextflow

I was trying to run a Nextflow pipe that had this common issue of  `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`  at random times and I fixed it by changing the Ulimit parameter by typing `ulimit -s unlimited` in my terminal but now I want to set the default values as they where. Do I need to set the values by hand or theres any way to set them by using a command? Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Setting soft limits using the `ulimit` command will only affect your current shell/execution environment and these changes will be lost if you close your terminal session. If you open up a new terminal, you will pick up the default limits. Once you know what the default limits are, you can go back and manually change them if needed. Note that `ulimit -a` lists all *current* resource limits.